# str.find() seems to be ignoring the first character in a string

Tags: c++

In the application where the complete code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Insert";
    int kint = 0;

    if (kint == 0 && str.find("Insert"))
    {
        cout << "found" << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

No cout ever occurs. If you search for "nsert" instead then the cout does occur.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the fact that when `find` doesn't return anything, it returns `npos` not zero. A return value of 0 means that it found what it was looking for at index 0.

```
if (kint == 0 && str.find("Insert) != string::npos) { ... }
```

[NOTE: for about 15 seconds this answer claimed, wrongly, that `str.find()` returns `str.end()` on failure. This was rubbish. My apologies if anyone read the wrong version and believed it.]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look what the find function returns :

> Return Value The position of the first
>   occurrence in the string of the
>   searched content. If the content is
>   not found, the member value npos is
>   returned.

Since you search for "Insert" it returns 0 and the if fails

Answer (score 0):

Actually it returns the position, which is 0 in your case. 0 is converted to false...
look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

You need to check for `str.find("Insert") != std::string::npos` in your if statement

Answer (score 0):

find() returns the position of the found char. So the first char's position is 0, converted to false in boolean.
You should compare with npos

```
if (kint == 0 && str.find("Insert") != str::npos)
{
    cout << "found" << endl;
}
```